# sqlmap: testing javascript or json parameters

Tags: sql-injection

I have a parameter in a POST request which is in the following format:

ParamName= `< r username="123" password="456" x="" y=""/>`

and I want to test username and password which are two HTML input controls on the webpage using SQLmap. how should I use sqlmap for this kind of requests or for example JSON parameters which are like parametername={ username:value1 , password:value2}?

Comment: can you post the HTTP request?

Comment: next time give heads up after editing your post...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply use a text file with your HTTP request in it and add a `*` to where you want sqlmap to perform the injection. Then start sqlmap with the `-r http_request.txt` option.

As an example for the file:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com

parametername={username:*, password:*}
```

Comment: Will this work with the --data="{json:*}" flag?

Comment: Yes, this will work but keep in mind that if you're using the `-r` option, you will have to put the `--data` part in the request file. If you're using the `-u` option, this will work as you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

[Here this is a simpler tool for sql injection testing](http://itsecteam.com/products/havij-advanced-sql-injection/)

You can also manullay try changing the request as fallows (and with different variations by using cheat sheets avaliable on the Internet )

ParamName= < r username="123" and ""="## password="456" x="" y=""/>

hashtags will (yeah its no more number sign or pound key :( ) tell sql to ignore the rest so it will take it as right.

user can also input (123" and ""=" ) from the interface for username and your code would add final " which would do the same affect with example above

etc...
   Google sql injection cheat sheet and examples...